# CRM Workflow Configuration file

Tags: c#, workflow, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I have created a Custom Workflow in Dynamics CRM 2011.
I wanted to store my configuration (connection string, url, etc) inside an app.config.

Is it possible to retrieve that value from a configuration file (app.config / web.config) in the Custom Workflow code?

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you cant really as there isnt one available to use. I suppose you might be able to add it to the app.config of the Async service, but then that probably isnt supported and I'm not sure how you would read it.

I would suggest instead:

1. Use a settings record in Crm itself
2. Have them as inputs to your workflow activity (from the Crm Ui)
3. Use a web resource